# C++11: SFINAE in template parameters, GCC vs Clang

Tags: templates, c++11, gcc, clang, sfinae

I want to implement a little trait-class to determine if a type has overloaded `operator()` properly, so that I can query a type like so:

```
FunctorCheck<F, void(int, char)>::value
```

Originally, I got an idea on how to implement this from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083593/is-an-is-functor-c-trait-class-possible), but after seeing a [Cppcon lecture on TMP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Am2is2QCvxY), it dawned on me that this problem could be solved much more elegantly. This is what I came up with, and this compiles and runs flawlessly on Clang 3.5.0:

```
template <typename ...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename Functor, typename ... Args>
using FunctorReturn = decltype(declval<Functor>()(declval<Args>()...));

template <typename Functor, typename Signature, typename = void>
struct FunctorCheck: public std::false_type
{};

template <typename Functor, typename R, typename ... Args>
struct FunctorCheck<Functor, R(Args...), 
    void_t<FunctorReturn<Functor, Args ...>> // SFINAE can kick in here
> : public std::is_same<R, FunctorReturn<Functor, Args ...>>::type
{};
```

As you might have noticed, I'm using the proposed C++17 `void_t` to exploit SFINAE in the template parameters of the specialization. When `FunctorReturn` receives a `Functor`-type that is incompatible with the argument-list, `void_t<FunctorReturn<Functor, Args ...>>` will be ill-formed, SFINAE will kick in and the non-specialized version will be instantiated. If the former expression is well-formed, `std::is_same` compares the return-types to determine if we have a match.

In the lecture mentioned before, Walter Brown mentions that this technique has worked from day 1 on Clang, and has *not* worked on GCC from day 1, simply because they chose different implementations on something the standard failed to specify. However, given that this version is ***so much more elegant*** than what I had before, is there anything I can do to make this compile on GCC (>= 4.9)?

(Also, does anyone have any clue as to how this would behave on recent versions of Visual Studio?)

Comment: He meant to use `template<class...> struct voider{using type=void;}; template<class... Ts> using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;` instead of plain `void_t`

Comment: Nice! If you post that as an answer, I'll accept (assuming that it works) :-)

Comment: `std::is_same` looks wrong -- you invoke via converting, you should return as well.  `std::is_same<R,void>{} || std::is_convertible<FunctorReturn<Functor,Args...>,R>{}` would be a better test, to me.

Comment: @T.C. Yup, you're right. Didn't show up in any of my google queries, nor related SO questions. Sorry!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was [CWG issue 1558](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558). The *unspecified* part was treatment of unused arguments in an alias template. In GCC < 5.0 the unused arguments can't result in a substitution failure, hence `void_t` [fails to verify your functor call](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc1b15d9d373503f), and tries to instantiate a class template specialization, which results in a hard error.

A workaround for GCC (< 5.0) is the following implementation:

```
template <typename...>
struct voider
{
    using type = void;
};

template <typename... Ts>
using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a11c773b180a01d)