# How is std::is_constructible<T, Args> implemented?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, std

So far I can't find anything ELI5 online. For a learning project I would like to implement my own is_constructible. Can someone explain how it works, please?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible):

> [I]f the variable definition `T obj(std::declval<Args>()...);` is well-formed, `value` is equal to `true`, else `value` is `false`.

Checking whether code is well-formed can be done with SFINAE techniques, for example the `void_t<>` trick (expected to be part of the C++1z standard library):

```
template <class...>
using void_t = void;

template <class, class T, class... Args>
struct is_constructible_ : std::false_type {};

template <class T, class... Args>
struct is_constructible_<
    void_t<decltype(T(std::declval<Args>()...))>,
T, Args...> : std::true_type {};

template <class T, class... Args>
using is_constructible = is_constructible_<void_t<>, T, Args...>;
```

The `using` hoop-hopping is there to place the `void_t<>` argument first. It usually comes last with a default type, but that position is held by the variadic `Args` pack.

When `is_constructible_` is instantiated for `<void, T, Args...>`, the compiler tries to instantiate the specialization first. This only succeeds if the contents of `void_t<...>` are semantically valid, that is, `T(std::declval<Args>()...)` could be executed correctly -- as specified in the requirements of `is_constructible`. Note that I have used a temporary instead of a local variable, but to my knowledge the rules don't change between the two. The specialization inherits from `std::true_type`, which yields a `true` `value`.

If the specialization cannot be instantiated (i.e, `T(std::declval<Args>()...)` is not valid), the compiler falls back to the general template, which can always be instantiated. This one inherits from `std::false_type`, which yields the `false` `value`.

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ba810f196b557f7)

More precise traits, such as `std::is_trivially_constructible`, need more advanced knowledge of the language rules to craft the expression whose validity should become the value of the trait. If this proves infeasible from inside the language, such as with `std::is_standard_layout`, then the compiler itself has to provide an intrinsic function to retrieve the value.

Comment: This isn't exactly equivalent to `std::is_constructible`, because `T(Arg)` is equivalent to a C-style cast - so your `is_constructible<intptr_t, int*>` is `true`, while the `std` one will return false.

Comment: Try
`template <class T, class... Args>
struct is_constructible_<
    void_t<decltype(::new T(std::declval<Args>()...))>,
T, Args...> : std::true_type {};
` for the specialized template.

Comment: See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/boost/type_traits/is_constructible.hpp