# Check at compile time that a template parameter is a kind of string

Tags: c++, type-traits, c++98

Let's say I've got a function:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T& arg) {
   ASSERT(is_valid<T>::value == true);
   // ...
}
```

Where `is_valid` check if `T` is either a string or an integer. I can easily make structures that can do that for me:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_integer { static const bool value = false; };
template <>
struct is_integer<int> { static const bool value = true; };

template <typename T>
struct is_string { static const bool value = false; };
template <>
struct is_string<std::string> { static const bool value = true; };
```

And then use both of these structure to check the argument:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_valid { 
    static const bool value = is_string<T>::value || is_integer<T>::value; 
};
```

However it seems I miss some string types. Is there a C++ type that target all string types? Is there already a structure or function that can do that for me?

I got:

- `std::string`
- `char*`
- `char[]`

in my `is_string` structure but it doesn't seem to be enough. I haven't passed `const` and `&` (references) as it is not tested that way: from a `const T&` argument, only `T` is tested.

Comment: What makes you think you are missing some types? Did you pass something that should have been detected as a string but wasn't? What did you pass?

Comment: What do you consider as string ? `/*const*/char[N]`, `std::wstring`, `QString`, `vector<char>`, ...

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string this may or may not help

Comment: Think about using #include <type_traits>. std::remove_cv, std::is_same, std::is_constructible

Comment: You first must define a definition of a string (Jarod's comment). A suggestion, `T` is a string iff `std::string(T const&)` exists; i.e. `is_constructible<std::string, T>::value == true` (Andrey's comment).

Comment: @AndreyNasonov I don't use C++11 unfortunately
@nwp When I call `foo("bar")`, the assertion fails. 
@Jarod42 A string could be anything to me. The thing is I don't know how `"const static"` is seen by the compiler... And I don't really know where is the information. 
@Charles I tried using `std::basic_string` in my struct but it is not seen as type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the following definition of a *string* suits you:

> `T` is a string if and only if it can be used to construct an `std::string`.

Then, you could define `is_string<T>` with:

```
template <typename T>
using is_string = std::is_constructible<std::string, T>;
```

And [`is_constructible` is definable in C++98](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40439909/5470596) :)

---

[Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6099c98f83e36b1b):

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
using is_string = std::is_constructible<std::string, T>;

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << is_string<const char*>::value << "\n"
        << is_string<volatile char*>::value << "\n"
        << is_string<std::string>::value << "\n"
        ;
}
```

Output:

> true
>   false
>   true

Comment: I don't think you need the first struct template

Comment: @Caleth in deed

Comment: It suits me yes. I like the idea. I need to find a way to do this in C++98

Comment: @baptiste You can define `std::is_constructible` in C++98.

Comment: I saw the same question ;)