# Can std::is_invocable be emulated within C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I'd like to use std::is_invocable, however we are using c++11 standard, while is_invocable is available only from c++17.

Is there any way to emulate the functionality using c++11?

Thank you

Comment: There seems to be an equivalent in the [gcc implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/type_traits#L2672).

Comment: Did you try the `std::__is_invocable`?

Comment: did you check Boost library, https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/is_invocable.html

Comment: @Ron -- `std:__is_invocable` is not part of C++11, nor of any other version of the C++ standard. It looks like an interanal detail for a particular library implementation.

Comment: @PeteBecker I see. The comment [few lines back](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/type_traits#L2661) suggests it is some sort of equivalent for the C++11. Or that was my understanding.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try this implementation:) Taken from boost C++ libraries. I've tested it with VS2017 with standard C++14.

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
struct is_invocable :
    std::is_constructible<
        std::function<void(Args ...)>,
        std::reference_wrapper<typename std::remove_reference<F>::type>
    >
{
};

template <typename R, typename F, typename... Args>
struct is_invocable_r :
    std::is_constructible<
        std::function<R(Args ...)>,
        std::reference_wrapper<typename std::remove_reference<F>::type>
    >
{
};
```

Comment: It requires the library to implement [LWG 2132](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2132) though.