# C++ template function, specify argument type of callback functor/lambda while still allow inlining?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

What we usually do is like this:

```
template<class Callback>  
void some_func(Callback const& callback){
   ....
}
```

What I want is like:

```
template<class void Callback(int)>  //<---
void some_func(Callback const& callback){// not valid
   ....
}
```

We can specify the type if we pass by `std::function` but it disable inlining.

Comment: [function_view](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html) might interest you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have C++20 that's is exactly what the concepts are for

```
#include <concepts>

template<typename T>
concept Callback = requires(T a) {
    { a(int()) }  -> std::same_as<void>; 
};

template<Callback T> 
void some_func(T const& callback){
  //  ....
}

int a(int) {
    return 0;
}

void b(int) {}

int main() {
    // below does not compile
   // some_func(a);
    some_func(b);
}
```

Comment: Possibly reuse [invocable concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable).

Comment: @Jarod42 invocable does not check return type

Comment: `template <class F, typename Ret, class... Args >
concept Callable =
  std::invocable<F, Args...> &&
  std::same_as<Ret, std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>>;`.

Comment: @Jarod42 care if I copy it to answer?

Comment: You can do it. Sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [std::enable_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) with [std::is_invocable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) (requires C++17 but [can be implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51188325/4074081) in C++ 14):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename F,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F, int>>>
void foo(F&& f)
{
    f(1);
}

int main()
{
    // OK
    foo([](int x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; });

    // Still compiles since int is convertible to double
    foo([](double x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; });

    // Compilation error
    // in gcc:
    // error: no matching function for call to 'foo(main()::<lambda(std::string)>)'
    foo([](std::string x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; });
}
```